# What does it mean to say: "one can even speak of hype"?

Tags: expressions, academia

In a paper I encountered with this sentence:
"Smart grids have attracted significant attention lately, and one can even
**speak of hype**."

The above sentence is from: Vanfretti, Luigi, Dirk Van Hertem, and Jan Ove Gjerde. "Smart transmission grids vision for europe: Towards a realistic research agenda." Smart Grid Applications and Developments. Springer London, 2014. 185-220.

In macmillan dictionary "hype" means: the use of a lot of advertisements and other publicity to influence or interest people. However, I wonder what it means collocated with "speak of" in the above sentence

What does it mean to say: "one can even speak of hype"?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  You should start out by consulting a general reference for the definition of the word "hype", and then tell us what you find. Questions which do not show basic research are subject to close. If you need assistance in framing a question, please visit our Help Page ["How to ask a question"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It simply means to talk about, to mention, etc. You should edit your question to include your comments, but I suspect you already have your answer now. BTW, "hype" can also mean an "exageration of the truth" as in _hyperbole_.

Comment: Thank you @Cascabel I got the answer. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Ok, I do not delete it. It may help someone, sometime. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the word *hype* here connotes an increase in awareness, growing realization about the use of “smart grids.”
Smart grids have attracted significant attention lately, even so that one can speak of it as it is distinctly recognized.

In other words, one can unhesitatingly speak of smart grids as this technology is gaining ground and people increasingly know about it.

Hope it helps!